# Differential receiver: 75176 vs optocoupler

Tags: pcb-design, components, opto-isolator, differential, component-selection

I have an incoming differential signal for my PCB to be designed which I have to read.

I also need to isolate the incoming differential signals from my PCB's digital system, so I will be using a dual-channel EL0631, which is just two 6N137 stuck together in a small SMD package. If you don't know these part numbers, they are just high speed octocouplers (forward voltage 1.4V, logic high threshold 2mA, max current 5mA.)

Normally, I would send the incoming differential signals to a 75176, then pass their output to our EL0631 optocoupler and then to a microcontroller.

Now I came across some designs where they just chucked away the differential receiver and connected it directly to the optocouplers. That made me wonder if I really needed the receiver IC because the optocoupler would read the differential signals just fine and, according to my understanding, have similar noise suppression as the receiver, since the line is still balanced.

Does the 75176 do any special magic to suppress the noise, or would I get similar results if I just connected it to the optocoupler?

The fundamental frequency of the incoming signal is 10 MHz.

EDIT:

The input of one differential pair goes into one optocoupler, so what I mean is only one channel of EL0631 is used for one differential pair. meaning one EL0631 takes input of two differnetial pair.

Would I need a termination resistor?

Comment: Please add more details about the driving side. What chip? Point-to-Point or multidrop? Cable type and length?

Comment: The signals are coming from rotary encoder/ linear encoder. 
Communication is point to point.
Cable type is CAT6 length upto 10 meters.

Comment: Then we need to know the specifications of the encoder output.

Comment: @Mattman944 The datasheet dosen't say much except it uses RS422 standards. I think the bus is 5V. so I assume it should behave like 75176 in driver mode.

Comment: This sounds backwards: normally isolation goes in front of RS-422 so that differential can be transmitted on an isolated circuit, further improving its already good EMC immunity. I suppose one could use such a driver as an LED driver but it's very unconventional and a regular CMOS inverter/buffer or transistor even will do. Also 10MHz is about three orders of magnitude higher than any optical encoder I know; not sure about other types.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am confused by your statement on using isolation in front of RS-422. You mean to say that the isolator is on the transmitter side?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes you are right typical incremental enocders output in range of 1Mhz to 2Mhz, but some absolute encoders use BiSS bus for communication running upto 10Mhz

Comment: Ah, okay. So it could be general communcations.

Answer (score 0):

If you are truly operating at 10Mbps, then the 75176B must be used. The 75176 may be used at lower data rates. See the datasheet. RS422 is expecting a \$100 \Omega\$ cable terminated with a \$100 \Omega\$ resistor.

Galvanic isolation requires an isolated power supply for the 75176.

The EL0631 requires a current (min 5 mA) input with a voltage compliance of 1.8 V. A series resistance of \$100 \Omega\$ is required to meet RS422 loading. The 75176 may not be necessary, but testing is necessary.

Reference designs are provided in the datasheet for a \$50 \Omega\$ receiver.

Comment: Yes I actually meant 75176B, I forgot about it since 75176A is NOT the default option when we buy those over here.

Comment: What do you mean by "Galvanic isolation requires an isolated power supply for the 75176"? If you meant, to implement isolation, one needs to have an isolated supply for 75176 and the isolator IC, then yes, I understand that. But also, I am using optical isolation over here and not galvanic isolation, so I am confused about what you actually meant to imply.

Comment: @Bubu: Galvanic isolation separates to systems electrically for all power, ground and signals. Optical coupling is a low cost method that is applied to signals, Transformers are also used. To achieve power and ground isolation, separate power supplies are required on either side of the barrier. Signal transformers isolate passively. The 75176 requires power to function and so must also be isolated. If you can use the EL0631 as a receiver, (I'm not saying that you can), the isolated power supply would not be required.